# spinner on splash screen is not rotating

Tags: android, angular, ionic3, splash-screen

i m using ionic 3.In my app on splash screen a circle is rotating but now on the place of circle a fixed arrow icon is shown can any one tell me how can i fix this problem

[image]

Comment: can you share the code you have?

Comment: which you want ? after testing on multiple devices i find out that its working on some  device but not all devices

Comment: I meant code you have for the spinner, before and after replacing it with arrow

Comment: i did not any thing in spinner part that's why i m asking if i have done i simply revert code on my git any way i tried that too.but it working on some mobile that the big issue here